# Google Spreadsheets / Excel: Replace every nth Space

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a string of text where i need to replace every 3rd space or every 9th character with a delimiter ";" or ":"

Example 1 -

> 94 B7 13 94 A9 13 91 9F 13 94 92 11

Result

> 94 B7 13;94 A9 13;91 9F 13;94 92 11

Example 2 -

> 94 B7 13 94 A9 13 91 9F 13 94 92 11 9D 55 12

Result

> 94 B7 13;94 A9 13;91 9F 13;94 92 11;9D 55 12

How can i do this Google spreadsheets or Excel (Preferred Google spreadsheet)

Comment: Do you have a limit on the length of the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In excel you can use the substitute function, last argument is to tell the space you want to replace.

To substitute only the 3º space

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1;" ";";";3)
```

Depending on your regional settings you may need to replace field separator ";" by ","

Comment: Thanks, any chance this can be achieved in Google Spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use a macro in Excel that loops through each cell. If you select the range containing the cells you want to modify and run the following macro, you should get every 3rd space in each cell replaced with a `;`.

```
Sub InsertDelimiter()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim SpaceCount As Integer

    For Each cell In Selection
        SpaceCount = 0
        For i = 1 To Len(cell.Value)
            If Mid(cell.Value, i, 1) = " " Then
                SpaceCount = SpaceCount + 1
                If SpaceCount = 3 Then
                    cell.Value = Mid(cell.Value, 1, i - 1) & ";" & Mid(cell.Value, i + 1, Len(cell.Value) - i)
                    SpaceCount = 0
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: You will have to copy this code to a new module in VBA. Here is a guide to getting started with VBA: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: I am not familiar with macros in Google Spreadsheet. In that case you would have to use a coding language called "Google Apps Script", but I have no experience in using that.